# Passing variable to jquery upload function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to web programming and I am trying to create a page where I can upload files. I currently have one upload button on my page which works fine, however, I would like two buttons, but using the same function.

I am trying to pass a variable(example in the code as comesfrom= tag or the logouploaddiv) to the function that will let me see that it came from a different button, so I can pass it to the PHP script via the dataType field in the jQuery below I can therefore handle the files coming from each button differently.

I have tried currently with $(this).attr("id") but this is clearly incorrect and wouldn't work anyway. Is there a way I can pass a custom tag to use and read within the function so I can see which button is being used to upload each file at the PHP end or would I just need to duplicate the $('#fileupload').fileupload code with a different ID for my other button? Thanks for reading!

```
<div id="logouploaddiv"><input class="btn btn-default" id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" comesfrom="logo_upload"></div>

<div id="progress" class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
</div>
<script>
$(function () {
       'use strict';

         var url = window.location.hostname === '' ?
                     '' : 'server/php';
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: url,
    formData: {type: $(this).attr("id")},
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
        location.reload();
    },
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
    }
}).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
    .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you need one handler for two input:file tags.
Try to use this jquery selector:

```
$("input:file").fileupload({your handler here});
```

Comment: Basically I need to know which button (theres only one in the example, but if I had two) is being used to called the $('#fileupload').fileupload and then set formData: {type: which_button_it_was}

Comment: I think you can get sender-tag inside fileupload (but use the selector I mentioned). Try to use $(this) inside the fileupload method.

Comment: Hi Sergey, yeah I did try that but all it returned was [object Object] I also tried just 'this'.

Comment: Hi Steve. Yes. It should return object. Now you can use $(this).attr("id") just as in your code and you should recieve the id of your imput tag. By the way, you can't use the same id for more than one tag. Javascript will not understand which one you want to use.

Comment: I tried this also, but it returned nothing at all. =/ I also tried $(event.target).attr('id') which returned nothing also

Comment: If I call it from the function it will return fileupload, however, If I include it in the jQuery $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: url,
    formData: {type: $(this).attr("id")},   I get nothing. Also how could I chose a different ID and still have it triggered by #fileupload.fileupload, I would need to duplicate the code? I guess I can just do that anyway, I was just trying to do it properly.

Comment: Have you tried this selector "input:file"? Well, you can always write a wrapper handler which will be called on input:file click event and inside of it you find your tag by $(this), remember its id to a local variable and apply fileupload to this object $(this). Then in formData you can use your local variable with that Id.